# Auto completion for Java code is not working with NetBeans 20 or 21 on Win 11

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts

I found Java auto completion that works with Ctrl+Space is not working NetBeans 20 or 21.
Wondering what the problem is.
I checked key map in options. I do see Ctrl+Space is the shortcut for it. I have NetBeans installed in Win 11 VM and I RDP to the VM. I don't think I had this issue before when using older version of NetBeans.

Any pointers?

Thanks